# Symfony execution of long running script

Tags: php, c++, symfony, process, symfony-process

I am using Symfony2 and I want to run a long script written in C++ (for example 60 minutes).

Now I do it via `shell_exec()`:

```
$pid = shell_exec('nohup my/program/written/in/c++.out some arguments > /dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $!');
```

If I keep refreshing a page the script runs fine, but if I go AFK the script is terminated with process of PHP server (/usr/bin/php-cgi).

Is there a way to isolate C++ program from PHP server process? With nohup the process has ppid = 1, so it should be isolated, but it is not.

Comment: consider using a symfony console command ... looks like you´re calling shell_exec() in a controller action which will terminate with terminating the http request AFAIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the Symfony Process Component : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

```
$process = new Process('nohup my/program/written/in/c++.out some arguments');
$process->run();
```

You will be able to run your process.

Comment: But this waits until the process is finished. Am I right? It is not good for long running processes.

Comment: @H.W. You can use `$process->start();` to run in background, however if the scripts ends (or, more accurately, if [`$process` destructor is called](https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/3.0/Process.php#L172)), then the process will be killed. If your script will definitely have to quit before the process finishes, use something like `nohup <your command>` (on linux). You'll still have to make sure `$process` is not garbage collected, so store it somewhere safely. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create symfony2 console command "myapp:my-command-name" that will run your c++ command

```
class MyStandaloneCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('myapp:my-command-name')
            ->setDescription('Will run standalone c++')
            ->addArgument('arg1', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Some arg');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {   
        $arg1 = $input->getArgument('arg1');
        $result = shell_exec('nohup my/program/written/in/c++.out '.$arg1.' 2>&1');

        $output->writeln('My cool command is started');

        return true;
    }

}
```

Then use  JMSJobBundle
http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation

Where you can create a queue of you console commands something like:

```
class HomeController ... {
 // inject service here
 private $cronJobHelper;
 // inject EM here
 private $em;
public function indexAction(){

 $job = $this->cronJobHelper->createConsoleJob('myapp:my-command-name', $event->getId(), 10);
        $this->em->persist($job);
 $this->em->persist($job);
$this->em->flush();
}


use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Entity\Job;

class CronJobHelper{

    public function createConsoleJob($consoleFunction, $params, $delayToRunInSeconds, $priority = Job::PRIORITY_DEFAULT, $queue = Job::DEFAULT_QUEUE){
        if(!is_array($params)){
            $params = [$params];
        }

        $job = new Job($consoleFunction, $params, 1, $queue, $priority);
        $date = $job->getExecuteAfter();
        $date = new \DateTime('now');
        $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC')); //just in case
        $date->add(new \DateInterval('PT'.$delayToRunInSeconds.'S')); 
        $job->setExecuteAfter($date);

        return $job;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, but it would be cooler to use `symfony/process` instead of `shell_exec()`. ;) One known "feature" from that function is that STDOUT and STDERR of the executed program is redirect to the owning PHP process, something most people wouldn't want.